# unity messed up by fglrx drivers

Tags: unity, fglrx

I tried to install the ati propreitary driver from this link...
[here](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.42&lang=English)

but somehow at the end it gave me some error.. and when i rebooted, unity complained that my h/w cant run unity.. and since then only the classic interface is available...

can anybody tell me how to uninstall the fglrx drivers?

there is nowhere written how to uninstall the drivers or what to do if the process aborts due to an error..

i am also so much frustrated with ati.. in 5 years amd got up with this driver which is of no use..as the installation process is suitable for people that know how to hack a kernel!.. and absolutly not for intermediate users.

any way to revert.. i dont want to do a clean install all over again.. or can i repair by reinstalling again..(not reformatting)?

update: this is the update process output and errors that i get.. i have ati mobility radeon x700 graphics..

> Do you agree with the license? [Y/n] y
>   Do you want to proceed with
>   Recommended installation? [Y/n] y 
>   Preprocessing Documentation Installing
>   Documentation ...  100% -
>   //usr/share/doc/ati/ATI_LICENSE.TXT 
>   Copying uninstall files for
>   Documentation  Preprocessing Display
>   and OpenGL Drivers Installing Display
>   and OpenGL Drivers ...  100% -
>   //usr/share/doc/ati/articles/4485.html
>   100% -
>   //usr/share/doc/ati/configure.html 
>   100% -
>   //usr/share/doc/ati/linuxfaq.html 
>   100% -
>   //usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libfglrxdrm.so
>   100% -
>   //usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so
>   100% - //usr/lib/xorg/modules/glesx.so
>   100% -
>   //usr/lib/xorg/modules/amdxmm.so  100%
>   - //usr/lib/libAMDXvBA.cap  100% - //usr/lib/libAMDXvBA.so.1.0  100% -
>   //usr/lib/libXvBAW.so.1.0  100% -
>   //usr/lib/libatiadlxx.so  100% -
>   //usr/lib/libaticalcl.so  100% -
>   //usr/lib/libaticaldd.so  100% -
>   //usr/lib/libaticalrt.so  100% -
>   //usr/lib/libatiuki.so.1.0  100% -
>   //usr/lib/libfglrx_dm.so.1.0  100% -
>   //usr/lib/fglrx/fglrx-libGL.so.1.2 
>   100% - //usr/lib/dri/fglrx_dri.so 
>   100% -
>   //usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/fglrx/fglrx-libglx.so
>   100% - //usr/include/GL/glATI.h  100%
>   - //usr/include/ATI/GL/glx.h  100% - //usr/include/ATI/GL/glxext.h  100% -
>   //usr/bin/fgl_glxgears  100% -
>   //usr/bin/fglrxinfo  100% -
>   //usr/bin/aticonfig  100% -
>   //usr/bin/atiodcli  100% -
>   //usr/bin/atiode  100% -
>   //usr/src/ati/fglrx_sample_source.tgz 
>   100% - //usr/sbin/amdnotifyui  100% -
>   //usr/sbin/atieventsd  100% -
>   //etc/ati/amdpcsdb.default  100% -
>   //etc/ati/atiogl.xml  100% -
>   //etc/ati/control  100% -
>   //etc/ati/logo.xbm.example  100% -
>   //etc/ati/logo_mask.xbm.example 
>   Postprocessing Display and OpenGL
>   Drivers  Copying uninstall files for
>   Display and OpenGL Drivers 
>   Preprocessing Kernel Module Installing
>   Kernel Module ...  100% -
>   //lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/kcl_acpi.c
>   100% -
>   //lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/drm_proc.h
>   100% -
>   //lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/kcl_agp.c
>   100% -
>   //lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/drmP.h 
>   100% -
>   //lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/firegl_public.h
>   100% -
>   //lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/firegl_public.c
>   100% -
>   //lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/drm.h 
>   100% -
>   //lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/make.sh 
>   100% -
>   //lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/libfglrx_ip.a
>   100% -
>   //lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/kcl_pci.c
>   100% -
>   //lib/modules/fglrx/make_install.sh 
>   Postprocessing Kernel Module  Copying
>   uninstall files for Kernel Module 
>   Preprocessing Catalyst Control Center
>   Installing Catalyst Control Center ...
>   100% - //usr/share/icons/ccc_large.xpm
>   100% -
>   //usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_cs.qm
>   100% -
>   //usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_da_DK.qm
>   100% -
>   //usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_de.qm
>   100% -
>   //usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_el_GR.qm
>   100% -
>   //usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_es_ES.qm
>   100% -
>   //usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_fi_FI.qm
>   100% -
>   //usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_fr_FR.qm
>   100% -
>   //usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_hu_HU.qm
>   100% -
>   //usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_it_IT.qm
>   100% -
>   //usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_ja.qm
>   100% -
>   //usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_ko_KR.qm
>   100% -
>   //usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_nl_NL.qm
>   100% -
>   //usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_no.qm
>   100% -
>   //usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_pl.qm
>   100% -
>   //usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_pt_BR.qm
>   100% -
>   //usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_ru_RU.qm
>   100% -
>   //usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_sv_SE.qm
>   100% -
>   //usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_th.qm
>   100% -
>   //usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_tr_TR.qm
>   100% -
>   //usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_zh_CN.qm
>   100% -
>   //usr/share/ati/amdcccle/amdcccle_zh_TW.qm
>   100% - //usr/bin/amdcccle  100% -
>   //usr/bin/amdxdg-su  100% -
>   //usr/bin/amdupdaterandrconfig  100% -
>   //usr/share/doc/ati/ccc_copyrights.txt
>   100% -
>   //usr/share/ati/lib/libQtCore.so.4 
>   100% -
>   //usr/share/ati/lib/libQtGui.so.4 
>   Postprocessing Catalyst Control Center
>   Copying uninstall files for Catalyst
>   Control Center  100% -
>   //usr/share/ati/ATI_LICENSE.TXT
>
> Installation complete. There were
>   errors during installation.  Details
>   can be found in
>   /usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log
>
> [Press Enter]

**/usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log** contents:

> Unloading radeon module... ERROR:
>   Module radeon is in use Unloading drm
>   module... ERROR: Module drm is in use
>   by radeon,ttm,drm_kms_helper [Message]
>   Kernel Module : Trying to install a
>   precompiled kernel module. [Message]
>   Kernel Module : Precompiled kernel
>   module version mismatched. [Message]
>   Kernel Module : Found kernel module
>   build environment, generating kernel
>   module now. AMD kernel module
>   generator version 2.1 doing Makefile
>   based build for kernel 2.6.x and
>   higher rm -rf *.c *.h *.o *.ko *.a
>   .??* *.symvers make -C
>   /lib/modules/2.6.38-8-generic/build
>   SUBDIRS=/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x
>   modules make[1](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.42&lang=English): Entering directory
>   `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-8-generic'
>   CC [M] 
>   /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/firegl_public.o
>   CC [M] 
>   /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/kcl_acpi.o
>   CC [M] 
>   /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/kcl_agp.o
>   CC [M] 
>   /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/kcl_debug.o
>   CC [M] 
>   /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/kcl_ioctl.o
>   CC [M] 
>   /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/kcl_io.o
>   CC [M] 
>   /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/kcl_pci.o
>   CC [M] 
>   /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/kcl_str.o
>   CC [M] 
>   /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/kcl_wait.o
>   LD [M] 
>   /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/fglrx.o
>   Building modules, stage 2.   MODPOST 1
>   modules   CC
>
>   /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/fglrx.mod.o
>   LD [M] 
>   /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/fglrx.ko
>   make[1]: Leaving directory`
>   /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-8-generic'
>   build succeeded with return value 0
>   duplicating results into driver
>   repository... done. You must change
>   your working directory to
>   /lib/modules/fglrx and then call
>   ./make_install.sh in order to install
>   the built module.
>   - recreating module dependency list
>   - trying a sample load of the kernel modules failed. [Error] Kernel Module
>   : Reboot required. [Reboot] Kernel
>   Module : update-initramfs

**when i run make_install.sh...**

> ashish@ashish-pc:~/Downloads$ cd
>   /lib/modules/fglrx
>   ashish@ashish-pc:/lib/modules/fglrx$
>   ./make_install.sh  ./make_install.sh:
>   line 24: /etc/ati/inst_path_default:
>   Permission denied ./make_install.sh:
>   line 25: /etc/ati/inst_path_override:
>   Permission denied You must be logged
>   in as root to run this script.
>   ashish@ashish-pc:/lib/modules/fglrx$
>   sudo ./make_install.sh  [sudo]
>   password for ashish: 
>   - recreating module dependency list
>   - trying a sample load of the kernel modules FATAL: Error inserting fglrx
>   (/lib/modules/2.6.38-8-generic/kernel/drivers/char/drm/fglrx.ko):
>   No such device failed.
>   ashish@ashish-pc:/lib/modules/fglrx$

Comment: remove them again, and boot into recovery mode within grub and try again

Comment: but how do i remove? sudo apt-get remove fglrx does nothing...sudo aticonfig says no adapter found.. i also tried to build a deb package by choosing option 2 in install process.. that too gave me errors.

Comment: Dont bother... ATI has stopped support for ait mobility radeon x700 long ago.. had to reinstall ubuntu.. heck ATI/AMD.Never going to have another ATI product ever.

Comment: well, it's not that they suck, they have to drop support for older cards, nvidia does the same

Comment: I see that you've posted code and terminal output as quote formatting. Quotes should not be used for this, and now it is impossible to remake it into code formatting without painstakingly redoing every like. Please repaste it and use CODE formatting.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get remove fglrx
```

then for newest ati driver:

```
wget http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/ati-driver-installer-11-4-x86.x86_64.run
```

***If you have a 64 bit system, then install this before anything:***

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Once dowloaded right-click the .run file and set it to run as executable.

then.

```
cd /path_of_the_file
```

***This is for 32 bit only:***

```
sudo sh ./ati-driver-installer-11-4-x86.x86_64.run
```

***This is for 64 bit only:***

```
sudo sh ./ati-driver-installer-11-4-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/natty

sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
```

Once it's done.

```
  sudo aticonfig --initial -f
```

that's all you have to do.

Alternatively you can add this ppa.

```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the fifth link on the page you will get some very useful information on how to troubleshoot the installation of the driver from the unofficial [wiki page](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Main_Page)

I recommend you also read the release notes that is located at the top - it is an ATI document that is well written for the average linux user and will give you installation and removal instructions for the driver.